# Is const variable declaration a type definition

Tags: typescript, constants, type-inference

With below `const` declaration of variable(`Point`),

```
const Point = {
        x: 1,
        y: 2
}
```

`Point.z = 6` says, `Property 'z' does not exist on type '{ x: number; y: number; }'`

Is `const` variable declaration a type definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. TypeScript is inferring the type based on what you have set your `Point` variable to. `const` is setting it up so that you can't reassign the `Point` variable. You will see the same behavior using `var` or `let` in your code.

Comment: Ah, something like `let x = 3`, typescript  infers `x` as type `number`. Similarly, typescript infers `Point` to be of type `{x: number; y: number;}`. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. It infers it based on the usage.

Comment: Infers at compile time